# sticky sessions jboss session replication cluster

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing

I have a jsf2 app in a jboss 6.x server. From everything I have read here and searching in google, it is always recommended to use sticky sessions. From my understanding, this means that the same node will always be responsible for the requests of the same user. Is this right?

If it is, what is the point of using jboss on a cluster mode? Couldn't I just have two jboss instances and let the load balancer distribute the requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that your system is multi-user. When the sticky session is used, the loadbalancer will balance users to both servers and they are used equally. But always one user is doing request to only one server. Advantage of this is that you don't need to replicate session and session data to all servers, which could unnecessary spend lot of resources.

Comment: Ok. I get your point about the sticky sessions. And agree that the performance should be better. But why would I need the cluster then?

Comment: I think that there are cases that you want to share some information/bean between sessions. I'm not sure but for example it's probably possible that You could have @ApplicationScoped bean shared for all users. Or EJB Stateful beans could be clustered. Or you can have only one been responsible for accessing database or managing connection pool.

Answer (score 1):

Session replication will help in case of a server shutdown or crash. If the server hosting a user's session goes down, then the user should not be prompted to login again. That is possible only if the user's session is replicated.